# Densely packed Xeon 5400 processors

Tags: cloud, socket, intel, supermicro, central-processing-unit

I'm doing lots of data crunching in a private cloud. I really like the price point of the Intel Xeon 5420 processor so I would like to run as many of these as possible. I have some running in Supermicro X7DWT motherboards. I would use more of these boards however they use a proprietary power supply pin configuration that is hard to come by.

Can anyone recommend a really low cost solution for running Xeon 5420's (socket FCLGA1366)?

Comment: Since when does the 5420 run on socket 1366?

Answer (score 1):

That's an old, slow and not-so-efficient processor... You won't find a modern solution that accommodates them now, as they've been eclipsed by several generations of Intel CPU... Nehalem, Westmere, Sandy Bridge...

Comment: I agree. The low price of old CPUs is a false economy. If you add in the cost of motherboard slots, power, rack space, and so on, the newer CPUs are a *much* better deal.